# file ending in .py considered .txt file and not launching with python idle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

im trying to follow this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRAIUA-Oc1Y&t=42s&ab_channel=KianBrose

first i tried with python 3.9.2
but the comments suggested using 3.7.9 so i uninstalled 3.9.2 and i installed 3.7.9 with shell (im a complete newbie in this i have no clue what any of this means)
and re did the commands inputed into the console in 3.7.9
after that i created the project folder inside of it i created the txt file and called it bot.py
how ever it was still considered a TxT file
the tutorial said to open the file with idle but when i tried to do that the option did no appear so i tried to directly make it open following this
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7
and after that the bot.py file did not open still considered a TXT file

sry for my english i know it is moist garbage im just tryna automate some things for a game and this still semes less tedious than actually doing the thing i wana automate plus they say programing gets u money

Comment: No, your English is not moist garbage. Also, maybe the file has the .txt extension and you are not able to see it. https://fileinfo.com/help/windows_10_show_file_extensions

Comment: 1. There should be no reason to uninstall 3.9.2 to install 3.7.9.  Unless there is a bug that should be reported and fixed, I believe the video maker is wrong here.  2. You should not edit files under `AppData`.  Make something like a `C:/Users/me/pyprojects` directory.  3. The easiest way to create a `something.py` file is to open IDLE first, select `File => New`, then `File => Save as`

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD. Then write:

```
cd "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7"
ren bot.py.txt bot.py
```

Comment: it worked, im so grateful for this answer Bless